# How to get select multiple records of subtable in lists in mysql and c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two tables "user" and "user_media" in mysql. The tables are as follows:

```
User:

id, name, phone, address
1, abc, 000000000, x lane, y city

user_media:

mid, user_id, media_url
j432, 1, http://.....sdfl.png
j84d, 1, http://.....snx8.png
```

I want to access the data in c# as:

```
string id;
string name;
string phone;
string address;
List<string> mediaImages;
```

How can I access the data in this way.

Comment: It is a inner join between the two tables. Do you have tried to use it? What are your efforts to solve the problem?. It is unclear if you need help on using NET libraries for Data Access or if you have problems in building an sql command text to retrieve the data.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your reply. Actually, the inner join only gives one row from the media table. If, I select using left join then the rows are redundant and I'm not able to use it in c#. I want to know if there is any way in mysql .Net driver or a way to get this kind of data

Comment: Please add the code that you have used to retrieve the data. if you have 1 user record and  2 or more user_media record with the same user_id I can't see why you get only one row with a INNER JOIN

Comment: SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN user_media ON user.`id` = user_media.`user_id`

Comment: it gives repetitive rows

Comment: @Steve One way I'm thinking for is to use GROUP_CONCAT. What do you think?

Comment: And if you run this query from the MySql Workbench you get only one row for each user in the user table also if there are more than one row in the media for the same userid?

Comment: For multiptle rows in media, it gives a repetitive row which gives the redundant results in my resultset

Comment: @Steve One way I'm thinking for is to use GROUP_CONCAT. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An INNER JOIN returns all the rows from the first table with all the rows from the second table that matches the ON condition. The matching row from the first table are duplicated to accomodate the data coming from the second table. It is your code that should insert the data from the Media table in the required list.

```
// This list will store all the records retrieved
List<User> usersList = new List<User>();

string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN user_media ON user.id = user_media.user_id";
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(.....))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con))
{
    // Starting values
    int currentUser = -1;
    User usr = null;

    con.Open();
    using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Loop over the results till the end
        while(reader.Read())
        {
             // If the current record is for a different user.....
             if(reader.GetInt32("id") != currentUser)
             {
                 // Create it
                 usr = new User();
                 // this should go in the constructor of User....
                 usr.MediaImages = new List<string>();

                 // Fill the field for the current user...
                 usr.id = reader.GetInt32("id");
                 usr.name = reader.GetString("name");
                 usr.phone = reader.GetString("phone");
                 usr.address = reader.GetString("address");

                 // Add the retrieved user to the whole list
                 userList.Add(usr);

                 // Prevent adding other elements to the list for the same user....
                 currentUser = usr.ID;
             }

             // For the current user add only the url info 
             usr.MediaImages.Add(reader.GetString("media_url"));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this is a lot of boilerplate code.... If you really want to abstract your code from these details I suggest to look at ORM (Object Relational Mapper) tools that could do this for you.

Comment: Thanks @Steve for your incredible help :) God bless you :)